# How to print PHP without refresh the webpage?

Tags: php, python, jquery, ajax, apache

First of all, thanks for all of the advices. 
So, I have a php, named `sys.php`, and I have a python program, named `button.py`, if I push one of the buttons the webpage prints out if the GPIO is low or high. Now this works perfectly, now I would like to reach that, it would get the information without refreshing the webpage, how can I actually do that? I've heard about Ajax and JQuery, but I down exactly know how does it works.

Here are the sys.php, some of the snippets were wrote in Hungarian, since I am from there, hope it doesn't bother you.

```
<html lang="hu">
<head>
<title>Project</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="icon" href="logo.jpg" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="projekt.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

</script>

</head>
<body>

<p class="small"><big>Project</big></p>
<p class="ex2">Choose GPIO </p>
<table style="width:95%">
  <tr>
    <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 7" name="GPIO7"></form></td>
    <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 8" name="GPIO8"></form></td>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 10" name="GPIO10"></form></td>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 11" name="GPIO11"></form></td>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 12" name="GPIO12"></form></td>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 13" name="GPIO13"></form></td>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 15" name="GPIO15"></form></td>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 16" name="GPIO16"></form></td>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 18" name="GPIO18"></form></td>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 19" name="GPIO19"></form></td>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 21" name="GPIO21"></form></td>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 22" name="GPIO22"></form></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 23" name="GPIO23"></form></td>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 24" name="GPIO24"></form></td>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 26" name="GPIO26"></form></td>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 29" name="GPIO29"></form></td>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 31" name="GPIO31"></form></td>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 32" name="GPIO32"></form></td>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 33" name="GPIO33"></form></td>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 35" name="GPIO35"></form></td>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 36" name="GPIO36"></form></td>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 37" name="GPIO37"></form></td>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 38" name="GPIO38"></form></td>
        <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" value="GPIO 40" name="GPIO40"></form></td>
        </tr>
</table>

<div id="demo">
<?php
                if(isset($_POST['GPIO7']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '7' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
                elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO8']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '8' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
                elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO10']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '10' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
                elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO11']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '11' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
                elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO12']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '12' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
                elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO13']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '13' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
                elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO15']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '15' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
                elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO16']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '16' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
 elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO18']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '18' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
                elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO19']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '19' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
                elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO21']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '21' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
                elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO22']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '22' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
 elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO23']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '23' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
                elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO24']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '24' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
                elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO26']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '26' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
                elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO27']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '27' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
 elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO28']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '28' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
                elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO29']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '29' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
                elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO31']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '31' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
                elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO32']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '32' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
    elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO33']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '33' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
                elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO35']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '35' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
                elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO36']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '36' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
                elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO37']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '37' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
                elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO38']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '38' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
       elseif(isset($_POST['GPIO40']))
        {
                $output=exec("sudo python /var/www/html/gomb.py '40' ");
        echo "<pre>A GPIO értéke: ";
                print_r($output);
        echo ".</pre>";
        }
?>
 </body>


</html>
```

And here is the python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

var=int(sys.argv[1])
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(var, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
print(GPIO.input(var))
```

Comment: Hello, you will have to use Ajax and it has little to do with your python implementation : I suggest you take a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to write a javascript function which asks the webserver asynchronously for new information. If there is any, you can manipulate the DOM to fit the new information.

To do this your php code needs to be in a seperate file as AJAX can only call entire scripts. Let's call it 'code.php'.

In the HTML you need a place to write in the value from the javascript.

HTML:

```
<p id="output"></p>
```

Javascript:

```
setInterval(myMethod, 1000);

function myMethod( )
{
  //this function will be called every second

  //now you can asynchronously ask the server
  $.ajax({ url: '/path/to/your/code.php',
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
                      //this function is called when the php script finished executing
                      //'output' is your new data
                      //now you can write it into the HTML
                      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
                  }
  });
}
```

DOM Manipulation: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

Ajax: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp